# R: Import 150 .csv files starting with XYZ from each of 100 tar.xy files

Tags: r, data.table, tar

I have a 100 tar.xy files each containing 300 (more or less) .csv files. I would like to import all the .csv files that start with XYZ from each tar.xy file and concatenate them.
I can do this when they're untarred but I'm a bit stumped how to untar them one by one and do this or what the most efficient way of doing this is. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

So far, I have:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
```

**For 1 tar.xy file**

```r
# Get names of files starting with XYZ I want
.files <- untar(tarfile = seed300.tar.xy,list=TRUE) %>%
            as_tibble() %>%
            select(value, starts_with("/XYZ")) #Find the files I want starting with XYX

# Untar only the ones I want
untar(tarfile = seed300.tar.xy, files=.files, exdir="~/Desktop/tempdir")

# Import them from that one tar.xy file
setwd("~/Desktop/tempdir")
tempData <-rbindlist(sapply(.files, fread, skip=1, simplify = FALSE),
                     use.names = TRUE, idcol = "FileName")

# Write as binary to concatenate with other seed files later
writeRDS(tempData,"seed300.rsd")
```

**For ALL the tar.xy files**

```r
list_of_files <- list.files("~/Desktop/tempdir",pattern = ".tar")

# Only untar PassengerExposure files
for(i in 1:NROW(list_of_files)) {
  
  print(paste(list_of_files[i], "which is", i, "of", NROW(list_of_files) ))
  
  #1. List the files you want within the tarred file
  print("#1. List the files I want within the tarred file")
  .files <- untar(tarfile = list_of_files[i], exdir = "~/Desktop/tempdir/", list=TRUE) %>%
              as_tibble() %>%
              filter(str_detect(value, 'Exposure')) %>%
              head()
  
  #2. Untar those specific files
  print("#2. Untar specific files")
  untar(tarfile = list_of_files[i], exdir = "~/Desktop/tempdir", files = .files$value)
  
  #3. Read in these files
  print("#3. Read in all files")
  
  .files <- list.files("tempOutputFile/", pattern=".csv") %>% as_tibble()
  selectCols <- c(1,3,5:8,9) #Only these columns
  
  tempData <- rbindlist(sapply(.files, fread, 
                               select=selectCols, 
                               skip=1, 
                               simplify = FALSE),
                        use.names = TRUE, idcol = "FileName")  
  
  # Write as binary to concatenate with other seed files later
  saveRDS(object=temp, file=paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(list_of_files[i], compression = TRUE),".rds"))
  rm(tempData)
  
}
```

Is this for loop the most modern efficient way of doing it? It's taking about 5 minutes per tar file so this will take a few days for the whole lot and this is only a test set of data.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; I have updated accordingly.

Comment: Ok. Good. So what is the problem? Does this code work on the one `tar.xy` file that imports the 150 `csv` files? And now the remaining problem is the need to iterate across the 100 other `tar.xy` files?

Comment: Thank you for coming back to this one. I've managed to create a working for loop that imports all the files but now takes about 5 minutes per tar.xy file. Do you think a better option exists?

Comment: About 300 .csvs per tar file is a large load to extract and combine. But I would avoid using pipes, `%>%`, inside for-loop and really you don't need to convert lists into tibbles as vectors can be filtered by string search (which means you may not need `dplyr` or `tidyr`). Also, `head()` seems strange to take first 6 and not all of your *Exposure* results.

Comment: Ahhh.. It turns out there are about 2000 files per tar file and of those there are 500. Head needs removing, it was just to test it. I turned it into a foreach loop but its even slower. I can't figure that out. Not really going in the right direction...